# Aligning circle image on left top corner of div

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the image, outside div has an overflow  circle image  on left top corner. I am trying to achieve that but not sure how to achieve it.

I am just playing with margin top and margin left position but that is not helping either.

Code:

```
<div class="decorative"> </div>

.decorative{
  position: static;
  width: 174.5px;
  height: 190.5px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;

  background: #EEA731;

  /* Inside Auto Layout */

  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  margin-top: -130px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Add all HTML & CSS code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it with having position relative for parent div and absolute position for circle div, managing circle div bg image left top width height and border radius 50%.

Sometimes on SO, people ask for too much info, I thought provided info was enough for people to help, here doesn't feel like help forum any more rather a boarding school where people are searching an opportunity to vote down your query haha